# What is the best way to govern a country according to Islam?

Tags: sharia, islamic-government, democracy

I have read elections are not allowed in Islam (for example, here: https://islamqa.info/en/98134 ).

Nevertheless, I would like to have more proofs and understand why.

Of course, any government must satisfy Sharia (this is, logically, compulsory). But, what about choosing the government? I mean, should we accept a government and its members without questioning? How do governors start their government? How can we be sure that they are the best to follow Allah's rules?

As we can see in today's Islamic countries, governments are not the best when they have to follow Sharia. So, I don't understand how a person (or a group of people) can govern a country without any control. I think it's not the best way (not 100% sure) that a country follow Sharia.

*Therefore, I would like to have proofs and understand what is the best thing according to Islam and how a person (group of people) can start to govern a country.*

Comment: This is an extensive topic to be answerable in this site. But as a study recommendation, if you're not held back by anti-Shia prejudices, you may want to have a look at the content and structure of Iran political system which represents an "Islamic Republic" under a [clerical scholarly leadership](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supreme_Leader_of_Iran) which also incorporates a guided democracy, and was founded in 1979 with vast popular support. See [Constitution of the Islamic Republic of Iran](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constitution_of_the_Islamic_Republic_of_Iran).

Comment: @infautaed, I red the following sites as you linked them, they look helpful. Hopefully they can be constructive for AmineGum as well. God bless you for presenting that ...

Comment: @infatuated , it sounds interesting! Thanks for your information, it helped me!

Comment: You're welcome. I'm glad you found it helpful!

Comment: Just to include, if **democracy** is not allowed and **consensus** is allowed in Islam acc. to IslamQA, then I would love to ask, **how are they both different** while choosing a leader ? (The person(s) whose opinion is not being considered obviously belongs to the minority)

Comment: https://islamqa.info/en/107166

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> elections are not allowed in Islam

Not true.

1. In front of Allah all human are equal. Color of skin, wealth, family or any other kind of  status, has no meaning in Islam. A big show of this rule can bee seen during Hajj, when millions of muslims from every cornor of the world come dressed in simple white clothing and pray side by side.
2. Quran clearly states that muslims should make their decisions with mutual consultation. Today with millions of people in any country, this would be only possible through elections.

   > 42:38 and those who answer the Call of their Lord, and perform As-Salat, and who (conduct) their affairs by MUTUAL CONSULTATION, and who spend of what We have bestowed on them;

Comment: Thanks. That's what I wanted to read, but I had found any source. Actually, I thought dictatorship (or something similar) is not fair, and, for that reason, I asked this question. But now everything has been clarified.

Comment: Glad to be of help. :-)

Answer (score -2):

As far as I know the first Caliph, whose caliphate is accepted unanimously by all Sunnis, came to power by public suffrage. How can a Muslim (at least Sunni Muslim) deny the right of people to choose their leader when first caliph was elected and they consider it all right?